# Object Generated From Entity Model Does Not Create Nullable Foreign Keys

Tags: entity-framework-4, foreign-keys, edmx

I have noticed some strange behavior when it comes to nullable foreign keys in my database. I have just started playing with the entity framework so I'm probably doing something wrong, but I cannot figure this one out.

Say I have the following two tables: (CountryID is a foreign key that is nullable)
[image: DB DIAGRAM]

When I create a new entity model I end up with this:
[image: DE DIAGRAM]

But the CountryID properties are set to Nullable (None) - instead of True. Obviously this is a really trivial example, but with a large database it would be difficult switch all of these manually. Is there any way to have the entity framework use a nullable `int?` for these foreign keys?